# English translation of Schwartz's papers on vector-valued distributions

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions, translation, generalized-functions

I am interested in systematically studying the theory of vector-valued distributions. The original two papers due to Laurent Schwartz entitled *Théorie des distributions à valeurs vectorielles. I & II* (1957-58) are written in French. Occasionally I have read mathematics papers in French when needed, with the help of Google Translate. But these papers are to the tune of 350-odd pages making it infeasible for such an undertaking.

1. Is there an English translation of these seminal papers by Schwartz?

The closest I have seen to a systematic exposition of vector-valued distributions is the book *Vector-valued distributions and Fourier multipliers* (http://user.math.uzh.ch/amann/files/distributions.ps) by Herbert Amann. But here some results are presented without proof and the reader is referred to Schwartz's papers. This brings me to my next question.

2. Is there a standard textbook (in English) which gives a self-contained account of the theory of vector-valued distributions?

What I am looking for is something like a vector-valued version of the series of books on Generalized Functions by Gelfand and Shilov (which had been promptly translated from Russian to English).

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. These papers have not been translated, as far as I know, however there exist lecture notes in english of courses by Schwarz on this topic:
   •  [Introduction to the Theory of Distributions](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.3138/j.ctt1vxmd4v)
   • [Lectures on Partial Differential Equations and Representations of Semigroups](https://archive.org/details/L_Schwartz___Lectures_on_Partial_Differential_Equations_and_Representations_of_Semigroups).
2. [Vector-Valued Distributions and Fourier Multipliers](http://user.math.uzh.ch/amann/files/distributions.ps), by Herbert Amann, is freely available.
   A more extensive list of text books is at [Good books on theory of distributions](https://mathoverflow.net/q/20314/11260)